# If $B = \left\{ {z \in \mathbb{C}:{s_n}(z) = {s_{n-1}}(z)} \right\}$ then $\operatorname{interior}(B)=\phi$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

let

- $A_j \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ $j = 0,1,2,\ldots,m$
- $P(z) = A_m z^m + \cdots + A_1 z + A_0$ is matrix polynomial and $z$ is a complex variable.
- $s_1 \ge s_2 \ge \cdots \ge s_n$ are singular values of $P(z)$.
- $B = \left\{ {z \in \mathbb{C}:{s_i}(z) = {s_{j}}(z)},i\ne j \right\}$.

***«Theorem»***

If $s_i(z)=s_{j}(z)$, $i\ne j$ for all $z$ in a non-empty
open set $U$, then $U=\mathbb{C}$.

By this theorem, why does $\operatorname{interior}(B)=\phi$?

Comment: This is false if $A_m = \ldots = A_1 = 0$ and $s_n(A_0) = s_{n-1}(A_0)$. Then $B = \mathbb C$. So its interior is not empty.

Comment: By $\phi$ do you mean the empty set, i.e. $\varnothing$ or $\emptyset$, rather than anything like $\varphi$? $\qquad$

Comment: Does "$s_i(z) = s_j(z)$, $i\ne j$" mean for ALL values of $i,j$ with $i\ne j$? $\qquad$

Comment: From the theorem, $B\ne C\implies $ Int$(B)=\phi.$

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp - Let $det(A_m)\ne 0$

Comment: @MichaelHardy -Yes.

Comment: If $A_m = \ldots = A_1 = A_0$ and $s_{n}(A_0) = s_{n-1}(A_0)$, then $B = \mathbb C$.

Comment: @user254665 - Thanks, why does $B\ne \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: I dk. I think that's what's needed to be shown, but it may depend on additional assumptions, as in a previous comment, (e.g.when every $A_i=0$)